# Using "extend" vs "extend for"

Tags: prepositions, time

What is the difference between using *extend* and *extend for*? What are the subtleties between these two phrases?

> I will extend your contract **for** as long as possible.

versus:

> I will extend your contract as long as possible.

Are they both even correct? Is it because using `for` implies a relation to time whereas without it, we are extending the object itself?

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extend+*%2Cextend+for%2C+extend+*_ADP&year_start=1800): It's not that unusual to use extend for.

Comment: I don't think **for** has anything to do with **extend** in your example. Rather, it has to do with "contract". Your contract is for three months, and I shall extend it for four more months. Or I will extend it for as long as possible.

Comment: They're both fine here because its an indeterminate time. If it was specific, you'd need for. "I will extend your contract for 3 months." "I will extend your contract 3 months." Ok, actually you could say the second one, but it sounds like something is missing.

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is understandable but not really correct.  A contract is for a specified amount of time (unless it's indefinite, in which case the whole extension thing is irrelevant anyway).